# Cannot install ffmpeg with Termux

Tags: applications, installation, terminal, ffmpeg

Why do I get a   `404  Not Found [IP: 104.18.36.234 80]` after attempting to install `ffmpeg`?

```
 # apt-install ffmpeg
    Reading package lists...
    Building dependency tree...
    Reading state information...
    The following additional packages will be installed:
      libbz2 libopus libx264 xvidcore
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      ffmpeg libbz2 libopus libx264 xvidcore
    0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
    Need to get 5595 kB/6094 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 19.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Err:1 http://termux.net stable/main arm ffmpeg arm 3.1.3-1
      404  Not Found [IP: 104.18.36.234 80]
```

The ip can be reached with `ping` and with a browser ([link](http://104.18.36.234/))

It is written `Direct IP access not allowed` is displayed on the page but that is normal since only `apt` from `Termux` may be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Termux requires frequent update: `apt update`